# Spring Controller Mapping Issues - Double Wildcard

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, frameworks, request, mapping

I would like to map the following URL:

`/resource/{path/to/git/repo.git}/{branch}/{path/within/repository}`

To a Spring Framework controller. However I am having some issues. I have tried the following pattern with no success:

`/resource/**.git/{branch}/**`

- matches `resource/anything.git/branch/path/etc` (no slashes in the path to git repo)
- does not match `resource/path/anything.git/branch/path/etc` as I would expect

I have also tried `/resource/**/.git/{branch}/**` in testing which behaves as expected, allowing any number of slashes in both Ant Pattern wildcards, but does not suit my situation with the added slash.

Is there any way to map this without resorting to `/resource/**` and doing the extra work of matching in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by using the mapping:

`/resource/**/*.git/{branch}/**`

A side effect of the example given in the original post working